# Two buttons in two difference views, acting as a single button

Tags: iphone, uiview, ios4, uibutton

I work on a project for iPhone iOS4 with Xcode 4.

My app uses a tabBar for two Views with two View Controllers.

I want to programmatically create a Button in a View and to have same button in the other view.

For "same button" I mean that buttons have same background Image, same Title and so on. Also, when I programmatically change first button  title also second button title change; same for backgrounds.

I was thinking something like "passing the pointer", but I do not know how to do it, how to pass a pointer from a View to another View. (I have a singleton GlobalData, if it can help.)

Thank you.

Comment: New file -> subclass of UIButton. Then include and use your custom UIButton object wherever you need it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is to create a custom UIButton, and then just use it wherever you need it. Once you change it in it's implementation file it will change globally.

Example CustomButton

```
//CustomButton.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CustomButton : UIButton{

}
@end


//CustomButton.m

#import "CustomButton.h"

@implementation CustomButton

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.type = UIButtonTypeCustom;
        self.frame = CGRectMake(170, 45, 150, 40);
        [self setTitle:@"Title" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:15]];
        [self setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bg_image.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }

    return self;
}

@end
```

Then use it like so:

```
#import "CustomButton.h"

...

CustomButton *myButton = [[CustomButton alloc] init];
```

Answer (score 0):

Although the approach looks a bit shady, but I do not know what the use cases are so here it goes.

You can create a UIButton subclass and make that a singleton. Or store that in the AppDelegate.

An interesting thing to note is that when you add the same object to a second view, it will be removed from the first view! So you will have to keep adding it back to the view when ViewController's viewWillAppear: method is called.

Comment: To clarify: I only suggested this because you want the changes that you do to the button in one ViewController to reflect on the button on another. 

If you don't want that, just do what @Cyprian said

Comment: To clarify: the two views represent the same thing in two different ways (graphical and tabular). The Button change a parameter, so both graphical and tabular representation changes. I want to be able to clic on the Button when I am in the view with graphical representation and also when I am in the other view.